# Проблемы с загружаемым архивом

Tags: php, android, http, okhttp

Отправляю на сервер архив через `OkHttp 3.12.0`

```
class UploadFileClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            File file = new File(folder.getPath(), "zip.zip");
            if (file.exists()) {
                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("file", "af.zip", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/zip"), file))
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://#####.ru/upload.php")
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.i(TAG, response.body().string()+" ОТВЕТ ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                //MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(Uri.fromFile(file)));
                //MediaType.parse("image/png");
                //http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Сам архив я собираю вот так

```
private void Zip(String source_dir, String zip_file) throws Exception
    {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zip_file);
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        File fileSource = new File(source_dir);
        addDirectory(zout, fileSource);
        zout.close();

        Log.i(TAG,"Zip файл создан!");
    }
    private void addDirectory(ZipOutputStream zout, File fileSource)
            throws Exception
    {
        File[] files = fileSource.listFiles();
        Log.i(TAG,"Добавление директории <" + fileSource.getName() +"> длина <"+files.length+">");
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.i(TAG,"for");
            // Если file является директорией, то рекурсивно вызываем
            // метод addDirectory
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                addDirectory(zout, files[i]);
                continue;
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Добавление файла <" + files[i].getName() + ">");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getPath()));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4048];
            int length;
            while((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            // Закрываем ZipOutputStream и InputStream
            zout.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

В этом архиве есть много папок, в которых есть фото. Сам он по себе собирается успешно. Проблема в том, что когда в архиве скапливается много папок и в них фоток то он просто не отправляется на сервер и `_$FILES['file'] = null`, максимум что мне удавалось отправлять это 2 папки в которых по одной фотке.

Сервер

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $url=dirname(__FILE__)."/".$name;
    $res=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $url);

}
```

Раньше `_$FILES['file]['error']` содержал `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`, и я это исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `php.ini` `max_file_uploads = 20` заменил на  `max_file_uploads = 5000`

И все работает!